# Topology not clean but why?

Tags: topology

I have the problem that my topology at one place looks weird. I put a a bevel modifier and a subdivison as modifiers. I just don't manage to make it clean.

[image]

Comment: maybe share your file? https://pasteall.org/blend/ ... also, do you have any reason to use so many edge loops for your cylinders? (if you use a Subdivision Surface modifier you sould not need so many)

Comment: That is just an effect of the subdivision surface

Comment: https://pasteall.org/blend/153a00682d8f480eace0f8e900d56000

Thank you for the uploading link, very helpful. And good to know that I used to many edge loops!

Comment: what do you mean by not clean? Maybe you're talking about the fact that the vertex seems to disappear? As WhatAMesh says, it must be because of the Subdivision Surface?

Comment: Yes, it has to do something with the subdivision. I don't understand why the edge is disappearing (on the area i marked red) and not on the other ones.